# Forms under bootstrap not uniform across FF/Chrome

Tags: html, forms, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I recently started using Bootstrap for my projects. All in all a very helpful projects, however I stumbled upon a problem with form appearance. Please see bottom pictures that I made looking at the following web page from Firefox: http://bootstrap-forms.heroku.com/

[image: Checkboxes are badly unaligned]
[image: Select is very ugly]

This is very very disappointing, because on Chrome it looks perfect. Not only I need to overwrite the default browser colours - I use  black theme in KDE/openSUSE, but I would also need to align the labels manually for Firefox - which I don't want to do!

Any suggestions for a quick solution to fix those forms across browsers? At least the aligning issue.

Firefox reports version 15.0.1, Linux / openSUSE version is 12.2.

Comment: When you mention KDE/openSUSE, are we to understand you are using Linux? It is always helpful if you can point out which operating system you are using, as the same browser may behave differently on different o/s.

Comment: Yes, openSUSE is Linux. I also included my Firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to edit `userContent.css` file located in `.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/chrome/` directory.

I have added the following:

```
* {
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

This property by default causes Firefox to use native system widgets on non-styled  buttons/radios/checkboxes etc. Unfortunately it seems buggy on my setup.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance for more details.